# IOS memory error while DELETE button is shown on Table View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I received a memory error while working on a project with Table View.

I replicated the storyboard on a new project and received the same error.

---

**Here's the storyboard layout:**

[01 - The Storyboard](http://i93.photobucket.com/albums/l47/carlodurso/Capturadepantalla2014-03-31alas173248_zps6ff44ae4.png)

**If the "Back" button is pressed while the Delete button is shown then I get a memory error as below:**

[02 - Running app and Memory error](http://i93.photobucket.com/albums/l47/carlodurso/Captura-de-pantalla2_zps240d75ec.png)

---

The code used for deletion is:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Remove the row from data model
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Request table view to reload
    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

I'm posting this question in order to learn more about Xcode and Objective-C.

1. Has anyone experienced something similar?
2. What process should I follow to debug this error?
3. Is there a Apple procedure to report this kind of errors?

Comment: I tried this in one of my projects, and I don't get any error. Can you post the new project somewhere for us to download?

Comment: Thanks rdelmar.
Here's the project;  
[link]http://ge.tt/1kmyMSV1/v/0?c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. Using Instruments, I found that a _canEditRowAtIndexPath: message is being sent to a deallocated instance of CDUTableViewController (after it gets popped off the stack by hitting the back button). This message is never sent when the table is in a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController -- I have no idea why that would be.

You can get around the problem by either using a UITableViewController, or by creating a strong property for the CDUTableViewController in the CDUViewController, and pushing in code rather than using a segue (that way your CDUTableViewController isn't deallocated on the pop).

Comment: rdelmar thanks for your help. I've tried the UITableViewController option and it works fine. Initially I didn't create a Table View Controller because I had trouble associating a custom class in IB, but definitely that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line: `[tableView reloadData];` - its implied.

And in the future you don't need to post a screenshot of Xcode just give us the error.

Comment: dtrotzjr, 
Thanks for your prompt reply and feedback.

Removing the line does not fix the issue apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following.  Use a modern property for your ivar, remove the declaration in curly braces in the implementation, and refer to that property as self.tableData everywhere in the class.  See comments within:

```
// 1) add a private interface
@interface CDUTableViewController ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@end

@implementation CDUTableViewController

// 2) delete the declaration in braces here

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // 3) refer to self.tableData everywhere in this class
    self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", // ...
}
```

The big fix comes at the time of delete.  Update your table to match your model after the delete.  Do this only for the delete editing style:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested this in the OP's project, and it doesn't fix the problem. I only see this problem with the table view in a UIViewController. When I do it in my project with a UITableViewController, I don't get the error. Not sure why but a message is being sent to the controller after it's popped (and deallocated).

Comment: Funny.  Runs just fine for me now.  Maybe I need to test more.

Comment: @rdelmar.  please try this http://ge.tt/5CeTqSV1/v/0 (built for 7.1 run on a 3.5inch sim)

Comment: I did, and it crashes just like the OP's (after swiping the cell to the left, then pressing "Back" without ever pressing the "Delete" button).

Comment: I confirm. But it crashed after the second try.

Comment: Geez.  I'm running it over and over.  About Sim: Version 7.1 (463.9.41).  About Xcode: Version 5.1 (5B130a).  Maybe clean, close, delete derived data and reopen?

Comment: I'm running the same versions of Xcode and the simulator. I did get it to not crash once, but all other tries crashed. If I add a UITableViewController to the storyboard, and put the same code in it as the OP's UIViewController, then I get no crash.